# Backbone.js: apply class with jQuery on click event in view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a pretty basic Backbone question. I want to apply a class (using jQuery) when an element is clicked. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this with Backbone views - I can capture the click event, but I don't know how to get the element in a way that jQuery can understand.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="options">
<ul>
<li>red</li>
<li class="selected">blue</li>
<li>green</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

*UPDATE - sorry, I should have given a less edited-down example, the real HTML is actually like this:*

```
<li><img src="red.jpg"><h3>red</h3></li> 
<li class="selected"><img src="blue.jpg"><h3>blue</h3></li> 
<li><img src="green.jpg"><h3>green</h3></li>
```

And my Backbone code looks like this:

```
var SearchFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#options'),
events: {
  "click li": "updateResults"
},
updateResults: function(e) {
  console.log('updateResults');
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
}
```

});

It isn't working as it stands - `updateResults` is being logged to the console, but the class isn't being applied. I think this because I'm not using `this` correctly. Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sup when using backbone events, `this` is set to the view. try using `e.target` instead of `this`.

Comment: Yeah, use `$(e.target)` instead of `$(this)`.

Comment: Hmm - thanks but in practice, I've got a bunch of stuff inside the `<li>` element - image and text. The class gets applied to whichever of these the user happens to click on - image or text. Is there any way I can specify that it should be applied to the `<li>`?

Comment: I need the syntax Backbone uses for the element on which the `click` event was set in the first place, I guess.

Comment: in that case try using $(e.currentTarget)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments from hajpoj's answers, it seems like you might need one of the following jQuery functions, applied with the 'li' element for $(e.target) (hard to tell without the exact html):

1. [.parents('li')](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
2. [.closest('li')](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: This also works, thank you, but I have accepted the answer above as it's pure Backbone.